# @Bean declaration with @Qualifier doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

Lets say I have a config class (JmsQueueConfig, see below). In this class, I want to configure multiple queues for my entire application. For one queue, there is no problem. However when I add a second queue and try to use one of these queues from a service (MemberService), then Spring-boot tells me

> Parameter 1 of constructor in
>   com.example.notification.application.jms.JmsEventPublisher
>   required a single bean, but 2 were found:
>           - queueAccountToNotification: defined by method 'queueAccountToNotification' in class path resource
>   [com/example/notification/application/jms/JmsQueueConfig.class]
>           - queueNotificationToAccount: defined by method 'queueNotificationToAccount' in class path resource
>   [com/example/notification/application/jms/JmsQueueConfig.class]
>
> Action:
>
> Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer
>   to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean
>   that should be consumed

Here is my Config-Class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJms
@ImportAutoConfiguration(classes = {
        JmsAutoConfiguration.class,
        ActiveMQAutoConfiguration.class
})
public class JmsQueueConfig {

   @Value("${APP_QUEUE_ACCOUNT_TO_NOTIFICATION}")
   private String queueAccountToNotificationName;

   @Value("${APP_QUEUE_NOTIFICATION_TO_ACCOUNT}")
   private String queueNotificationNameToAccount;

   @Bean
   @Qualifier("q1")
   public Queue queueAccountToNotification() {
      return new ActiveMQQueue(queueAccountToNotificationName);
   }

   @Bean
   @Qualifier("q2")
   public Queue queueNotificationToAccount() {
      return new ActiveMQQueue(queueNotificationNameToAccount);
   }

   @Bean
   public MessageConverter jacksonJmsMessageConverter() {
      MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
      converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
      converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("_type");
      return converter;
   }

   @Bean
   @Qualifier("p1")
   public EventPublisher eventPublisher(JmsTemplate jmsTemplate) {
      return new JmsEventPublisher(jmsTemplate, new ActiveMQQueue(queueAccountToNotificationName));
   }

   @Bean
   public MessageConverter messageConverter() {
      return new JmsMessageConverter();
   }
}
```

My Service:

```
@Service
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@AllArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class MemberService {

   @Autowired
   @Qualifier("q1")
   Queue q;

   @Qualifier("p1")
   EventPublisher eventPublisher;

   public void createMemberSubscription(final Member member) {
      final MembershipSubscriptionEvent event = new MembershipSubscriptionEvent(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), member.getEmail());
      //eventPublisher.publish(event);
      log.info("createMemberSubscription");
   }

   public void removeMemberSubscription(final Member member) {
      final MembershipRemovalEvent event = new MembershipRemovalEvent(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
      //eventPublisher.publish(event);
      log.info("removeMemberSubscription");
   }
}
```

I am new to Spring ecosystem and I might not have understand well the @Autowired and bindings. Any good documentation or example would be much appreciated.
On Spring and SoF, I haven't found any such documentation.

**Updated:**
JmsEventPublisher class

```
@Component
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@Slf4j
@AllArgsConstructor
public class JmsEventPublisher implements EventPublisher {

   final JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;
   final Destination destination;

   @Override
   public void publish(DomainEvent event) {
      jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(destination, event);
      log.trace("Sent event. [destination={}, event={}]", destination, event);
   }
}
```

Comment: what is `JmsEventPublisher` is it your custom class? if so can you put that code as well

Comment: Here you are (under the updated section)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have misunderstood `@Qualifier`
From the documentation, "**This annotation may be used on a field or parameter as a qualifier for candidate beans when autowiring.**"

In your case `@Qualifier` is of no meaning.

```
@Bean
   @Qualifier("q1")
   public Queue queueAccountToNotification() {
      return new ActiveMQQueue(queueAccountToNotificationName);
   }
```

Instead you should be doing like this

```
@Bean(name = "q1")
   public Queue queueAccountToNotification() {
      return new ActiveMQQueue(queueAccountToNotificationName);
}


@Bean(name = "q2")
   public Queue queueNotificationToAccount() {
      return new ActiveMQQueue(queueNotificationNameToAccount);
   }
```

Similarly remove `@Qualifier` on `eventPublisher(...)`

That doesn't solve all the problem. :)

As the exception indicates, spring is not able to autowire `Destination` field in JmsEventPublisher. Because it has two beans of type Destination(q1 and q2).
To solve this what you can do is .

Put `@Primary` on one of the bean declaration and then use `@Qualifier`.

```
@Primary
@Bean(name = "q1")
   public Queue queueAccountToNotification() {
      return new ActiveMQQueue(queueAccountToNotificationName);
}


public class JmsEventPublisher implements EventPublisher {

   final JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;
   @Qualifier("q1")
   final Destination destination;

     ..........

 }
```

Bottom line is For `@Qualifier` to work in case of multiple beans of same type, you need to put `@Primary`

Another option is instead of using @Primary, you can name the variables exactly as Bean names, then spring will automagically inject correct beans for you.  i.e.

```
public class JmsEventPublisher implements EventPublisher {

  final JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;
  final Destination q1; // q1 or q2
  .....
}
```

similiarly in MemberService

```
public class MemberService {

  @Autowired
  Queue q1; // q1 or q2
  .....

}
```

Comment: You were right, I have misunderstood the @Qualifier. Your example was just perfect for the understanding.

Comment: @ekemchitsiga please elaborate

Comment: @pvpkiran check the answer I have posted

Answer (score 10):

To correct the accepted answer,your understanding for the use of @Qualifier is correct. It can be used in two contexts. It can be used with a @Bean configuration method to provide a qualifier for the bean. If not provided this defaults to the bean name.

It can also be used at an injection target i.e method or field with @Autowired or @Inject annotation. At this context it assist Spring autowiring infrastructure to filter the bean candidates matching the injection target based on the qualifier(provided with @Bean method) if multiple beans are found

The cause of the error was due to

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class JmsEventPublisher implements EventPublisher
```

The @AllArgsConstructor will generate the following constructor

```
public JmsEventPublisher(JmsTemplate jmsTemplate, Destination destination){
   //body
 }
```

Spring will attempt to autowire JmsEventPublisher by constructor since it has one constructor which is not a no argument constructor. However the parameter of type Destination matches two beans of type Queue.

The solution is to either use an explicit constructor. ie remove @AllArgsConstructor and define constrctor as follows

```
public JmsEventPublisher(JmsTemplate jmsTemplate, @Qualifier("q1")Destination destination){
   //body
 }
```

or use field or setter injection instead i.e remove @AllArgsConstructor and inject fields or setter methods

```
public class JmsEventPublisher implements EventPublisher {

   private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;
   @Qualifier("q1")
   private Destination destination;

 }
```

Comment: what is the benefit of use @Bean @Qualifier"name" instead of @Bean("name") ?

Comment: It is currently the good answer to the given problem. The Lombok AllArgConstructor doesn't take advantage of the fields Qualifier annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Change `final Destination destination` to `final Destination q1` and it should work. I had the same problem and it worked for me.