# Spring ThreadPoolTaskExecutor Autowiring Different Instance

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, threadpoolexecutor

I'm using Spring Boot and have configured a `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` as follows:

```
 @Data
    @Configuration
    public class WorkflowThreadConfig {

        @Value("${threadConfig.corePoolSize}")
        private Integer corePoolSize;

        @Value("${threadConfig.maxPoolSize}")
        private Integer maxPoolSize;

            @Bean
            @Qualifier("threadPoolTaskExecutor")
            public TaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {       
                ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();       
                threadPoolTaskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(corePoolSize);
                threadPoolTaskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(maxPoolSize);
                log.debug("threadPoolTaskExecutor maxPoolSize  is : " + threadPoolTaskExecutor.getMaxPoolSize());
                threadPoolTaskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("workflow_thread_");
                threadPoolTaskExecutor.initialize();
                return threadPoolTaskExecutor;
            }
        }
```

When I `@Autowire` the `@Bean` into another class using a `@Qualifier`, I see the default number of Threads in the max pool size instead of the number I provided (10) from my configuration even after commenting out most of my code and just using a `@PostConstruct`:

```
@Component
public class WorkflowTaskScheduler {

//@Autowired
    //private WorkflowThreadManager workflowThreadManager;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("threadPoolTaskExecutor")
    private TaskExecutor taskExecutor;

    @PostConstruct
    public void workflowTaskScheduler(){
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPool = (ThreadPoolTaskExecutor) taskExecutor;
         log.debug(" Max Thread Pool count is : " + threadPool.getMaxPoolSize());
    }

}
```

Logs:

```
SpanId="">threadPoolTaskExecutor maxPoolSize  is : 10</L_MSG>
SpanId=""> Max Thread Pool count is : 2147483647</L_MSG>
```

Another interesting point to make is when i remove the `@Qualifier` annotation from both the `threadPoolTaskExecutor @Bean` and the `@Autowired TaskExecutor` I get the following error:

```
Field taskExecutor in com.package.WorkflowTaskScheduler required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - threadPoolTaskExecutor: defined by method 'threadPoolTaskExecutor' in class path resource [com/package/WorkflowThreadConfig.class]
    - taskScheduler: defined in null
```

Comment: Instead of using `@Qualifier` during bean declaration use `@Primary`.   Like this  `@Bean(name = "threadPoolTaskExecutor")
            @Primary
            public TaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor()` And keep the @Qualifier in your WorkflowTaskScheduler class

Comment: check my answer here. It is the same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48715714/configure-multiple-queues-in-one-class/48718862#48718862

Comment: @pvpkiran, i'm still seeing the same issue when i use `@Primary
 @Bean(name = "threadPoolTaskExecutor")
    public TaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {`

Comment: are you using `@Qualifier` in WorkflowTaskScheduler class?

Comment: Yes i'm using `@Qualifier("threadPoolTaskExecutor")`

Comment: Have you any other suggestions for this?  I'm still struggling to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:
1. Use a different qualifier then the camelcase. myThreadPoolTaskExecutor

2. Use @primary on your ThreadPoolTaskExecutor. SO it will be the one getting bundled by default